# Outputting console.log information on intern-runner

Tags: intern

When running `intern-client` I can see `console.log` output when running tests.

However, when running the same tests with `intern-runner` the log results from console are omitted.

is there any way to display those logs when testing on browser environment through `intern-runner`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just running unit tests, you can use [Intern's browser client](https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Running-Intern#as-a-stand-alone-browser-client) to run the tests, and have the console open in the browser. First, start a web server in your application's root directory (the same place you'd normally run Intern from). Access Intern's `client.html` file similarly to how you'd start `intern-client`. Assuming your web server is serving on port 8080, you'd use a URL like:

```
http://localhost:8080/node_modules/intern/client.html?config=tests/intern
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ intern-runner reporters=console
```

See also

```
$ intern-runner reporters=pretty
```

Comment: I don't think he refers to this kind of console.